# Expressing a vector as the sum of two vectors

Tags: vectors

I need to express **v** as the sum of two vectors, one parallel to **w**, the other perpendicular to **w**, where **v** is the vector <4, 3, 2> and **w** is the vector <1, 1, 1>.

This is what I have done:

Setup the equation that expresses **v** as a sum of two vectors where **a** is parallel to **w** and **b** is perpendicular to **w**.

**v** = **a** + **b**

Find initial value of **a** using the formula **a** = k**w** where k is a constant.

**a** = k**w**

= **k** * <1, 1, 1>

= (k, k, k)

Find initial value of **b** using the formula **b** = **v** - **a**.

**b** = **v** - **a**

= <4, 3, 2> - (k, k, k)

= <4 - k, 3 - k, 2 - k>

Solve dot product of **b** and **w** equal to 0 to find k and thus find the vectors **a** and **b**.

**b** · **w** = 0

<4 - k, 3 - k, 2 - k> · <1, 1, 1> = 0

4 - k + 3 - k + 2 - k = 0

9 - 3k = 0

-3k = -9

k = 3

So **a** = <3, 3, 3> and **b** = <1, 0, -1>

Therefore, **v** as the sum of two vectors is <3, 3, 3> + <1, 0, -1>.

Would this be the correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you arrive at is correct, but you can arrive at it with less steps by decomposing $\textbf{v}$ into its horizontal and vertical components via projection:
$$ \textbf{v} = {\rm proj}_{\textbf{w}}\textbf{v} + (\textbf{v} -{\rm proj}_{\textbf{w}}\textbf{v}) \quad \left(=\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}\right)$$
We arrive at the same answers you had:
$$ {\rm proj}_{\textbf{w}}\textbf{v} = \frac{\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{w}}{\textbf{w}\cdot \textbf{w}}\textbf{w} = \frac{9}{3}(1,1,1)=(3,3,3) = \textbf{a}$$
We see that $\textbf{a}$ is parallel to $\textbf{w}$ since it is a scalar multiple.
$$ \textbf{v} - {\rm proj}_{\textbf{w}}\textbf{v} = (4,3,2)-(3,3,3) = (1,0,-1) = \textbf{b}$$
We see that $\textbf{b}$ is perpendicular to $\textbf{w}$ since $\textbf{b}\cdot\textbf{w}=0$, and as desired: $(3,3,3)+(1,0,-1) = (4,3,2)$

Comment: Not sure that introducing the projection operator will clarify for the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust fair, but in the future it should still be fine since I still justified its use at the end with a quick verification (e.g. **b** is perpendicular to **w** since their dot product is zero) ? It was similar to what you wrote but not explicitly stated, and are concepts I assumed the OP knew.

Comment: That does look a lot simpler and cleaner compared to what I did. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Check:**

- $<3,3,3>+<1,0,-1>=<4,3,2>$;
- $<3,3,3>=3\,<1,1,1>$;
- $<1,0,-1>\cdot<1,1,1>=0.$

Passed.

---

You were solving

$$\vec v=\vec u+\lambda \vec w$$ with $\vec u\cdot \vec w=0$.

Multiplying by $\vec w$,

$$\vec v\cdot \vec w=0+\lambda \vec w\cdot \vec w$$ gives you $\lambda=\dfrac{\vec v\cdot \vec w}{\vec w\cdot \vec w}$ and $\vec u$ follows from

$$\vec u=\vec v-\lambda \vec w.$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!